# El texto del JLabel no se actualiza en la aplicación, cuando lo manipulo dentro de un bucle for

Tags: java, java-swing

```
public void deployWords(List<String> words) {
        
        for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++) {
            labelWord.setText(words.get(i));
        }
        //cleanPanel(panelViewWords);
        //add(panelInputWords);
}
```

Hola a todos, tengo dos problemas aquí. Uno de ellos es que no se muestra el cambio de texto en el JLabel. El otro problema es que debo hacer que haya un delay de 1 segundo, después de que se actualice el texto.

¿Alguien me puede dar una mano?. He intentado varias cosas, y leído varios blogs en internet pero aun no me queda muy claro el porque no se cambia el texto del JLabel cuando lo manipulo dentro de un bucle for, y el como puedo implementar el delay de 1 segundo.

Answer (score 0):

La manera de modificar el contenido del JLabel es tal como lo tienes en el for, por lo que quizás el problema esté en como has agrupado los componentes de la UI. Respecto el tiempo de espera, añadiendo un **Thread.sleep** en el bucle podría servirte.

He realizado una pequeña prueba con un JFrame, un JPanel y un JLabel y no me ha surgido ningún problema.
Te adjunto el código por si te sirve de ayuda.

```
public class SwingBasic {

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel word;

    public SwingBasic() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        word = new JLabel("...", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(word);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World", "Testing", "SWT"));
        deployWords(words);
    }

    private void deployWords(List<String> words) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            try {             
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                word.setText(words.get(i));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingBasic();
    }
}
```